# What is the licence on the photo used in this "Deep Space Image" question?

Tags: discussion

May I use your image [What kind of camera do I need to capture deep space images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19936/what-kind-of-camera-do-i-need-to-capture-deep-space-images) as my cover photo on FB?

Comment: The image in the linked question comes from
https://www.flickr.com/photos/bala_/4766723931/
It has a creative commons licence. Details here:
https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/

Comment: +1 for actually asking. :)

Comment: Out of interest, I'd like to know what does the creator of that photo consider a suitable way of attributing credit when it is used as a Facebook cover photo?

Comment: @user1515834 By the license, the credit may be provided in "any reasonable manner". While this ain't legal advice, I personally would consider putting the credit in the description (available to anyone who clicks on the photo) to be quite reasoanble.